# Simplify and evaluate expression in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, multiplication, simplify

I am trying to create a lisp function that evaluates and simplifies multiplication and addition arithmetic. 
The function should work such that when the user calls a function 
(simplify-Mult'(* 1 2)) it prints just 2 or 
(simplify-Mult '(*0 3 3 7)) prints just 0.

So far I have this

```
(defun simplify-multiplication (lis)
    (if (not (null lis))
        (if (member '0 lis) 0
        (if (member '1 lis) cdr lis
                (if (listp (car lis))
                    (cons(simplify(car lis)))
                    (if (numberp (car lis))
                        (if (null (cdr lis))
                            lis
                            (cons (car lis) (simplify-multiplication (cdr lis)))
                        )
                        (if (eq (car lis) '+)
                            (cons (car lis) (simplify-multiplication (cdr lis)))
                            (if (eq (car lis) '*)
                                (cons (car lis) (simplify-multiplication (cdr lis)))
                                lis
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )

            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Please consider investing a few minutes to learn about proper [Lisp code formatting.](http://dept-info.labri.fr/~strandh/Teaching/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write one single function simplify which applies the simplification rules for both multiplication and addition. If you want to recursively simplify an expression, first you have to simplify each one of the arguments and then apply the simplification rules for the corresponding operation.
The following could be a starting point:

```
(defun simplify (lis)
  (if (atom lis)
    lis
    (let ((args (mapcar #'simplify (cdr lis))))
      (cond
        ((eql (car lis) '+)
          (setq args (remove 0 args))
          (case (length args)
            (0 0)
            (1 (car args))
            (otherwise (cons '+ args)) ))
        ((eql (car lis) '*)
          (if (member 0 args)
              0
              (progn
                (setq args (remove 1 args))
                (case (length args)
                  (0 1)
                  (1 (car args))
                  (otherwise (cons '* args)) ))))
        (T (cons (car lis) args)) ))))
```

You would probably want to add other simplification rules, such as (* 2 (* 3 4)) => (* 2 3 4), etc.. as well as detecting wrong expressions such as (simplify '(+)).